# What should be the Preferred DNS Server for a new DNS Server or for a new forest?

Tags: dns

As the Preferred DNS Server, I found three options; either 127.0.0.1 (loopback address) or 8.8.8.8 or IP address assigned to the server.

What should I use for the Preferred DNS Server IP for a new DNS Server or for a new forest? And

Why Loopback address is used as the Preferred DNS Server?

Please resolve my above queries.

Regards

GNS

Answer (score 0):

Technet: [The loopback adapter should be included but never as first entry](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff807362(v=ws.10).aspx)

You mention a forest so I assume you are talking about a Windows Active Directory Domain? But you mention only DNS. Are you planning to set up an external DNS server?

Best practice is to setup up ADDS with AD integrated DNS. The first DNS entry should NEVER be 8.8.8.8 (or anything outside your domain) as this will make all domain resources unresolvable.

I would suggest you lookup some resources on the Microsoft Virtual Academy, eg [Understanding Active Directory](http://bit.ly/2aNIuxG), [Windows Server Administration Fundamentals](http://bit.ly/2ajyLdt), [Networking Fundamentals: Academic Edition](http://bit.ly/2agaFok) to get a better overview and understanding.

Comment: Thank you for replying. You assumed right i.e. Windows Active Directory Domain but I believe either its DNS configuration or Windows Active Directory Domain configuration, network settings is same so please guide me in regards of Preferred DNS Server and all network settings before instantiating and configuring a DNS, AD and DHCP.

Comment: I would suggest you do some reading, [70-410](http://bit.ly/1JTDVJC), [70-411](http://bit.ly/1zFXCj3), [70-412](http://bit.ly/1Me9cqW) which covers three Microsoft exams for getting MCSA 2012. Another solution, install hyper-v (if having a supported PC, MS license) or VirtualBox (free) and install the servers with next, next finish and play around (this should be definitively done if you decide to go for the exams - which are meant to be taken by people with at least two years experience). Or take some classroom training. Your request is not something to be done here. You get stuck, we help.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I am doing same thing. I installed Windows Server 2012r2 as a guest OS in VMware Workstation. As I am unable to attain any classroom so I am doing all myself with the help of ebooks and videos. I hope you'll resolve my above query.